# Using Jersey in Embedded Jetty

Tags: jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

I want to have some JUnit tests that run Jersey 2.2 in Jetty 9. Here is what I have:

The jobs service

```
...
@Path("jobs") 
public JobService() {

    @GET
    public Response list(){
        return Response.ok("Hello World!").build();
    }
}
```

The jetty embedded server code in my JUnit test

```
@Before
public void startServer() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    _server = new Server();
    _connector = new LocalConnector(_server);
    _server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{_connector});

    // Prepare rest service servlet
    ServletHolder _jersey = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(JobService.class, UserService.class)));
    _jersey.setName("restful service servlet");


    ServletContextHandler _servletCtx = new ServletContextHandler();
    _servletCtx.addServlet(_jersey, "/rest/*");

    _servletCtx.setContextPath("/ctx");
    _server.setHandler(_servletCtx);
}

@Test
public void testServer() throws Exception{
    _server.start();

    String response = null;

    response = _connector.getResponses("GET /ctx/rest/users HTTP/1.0\r\n");
    assertThat(response,startsWith("HTTP/1.1 200 "));
    assertThat(response,containsString("[]"));

}
```

Jersey does not send a response and I get no exception in the console when running this in eclipse.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the request was malformed, though it wasn't returning any error or throwing an exception. The request would just timeout. The change to fix this would be to add an extra newline to the request string to let the server know not to expect more data in the request.

```
response = _connector.getResponses("GET /ctx/rest/users HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
                                                                    ^
```